# What package is required for stat_summary function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, package

> ggplot(data=ED, aes(x=family, y=D_2017))+ stat_summary(fun=mean, geom='bar', fill=c('gray40','gray70'))+ stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom='errorbar')+ theme_classic()+ labs(x='Tree Type', y= '2017 DBH (cm)')

Warning message:
**Computation failed in `stat_summary()`:
Hmisc package required for this function**

Comment: It says right in the warning message......

Answer (score 1):

`stat_summary` is part of **ggplot2**, but `mean_cl_normal` is from the **Hmisc** package. You'll need both to run this code.